# Python: how to create a list of lists with increasing length, made of random numbers?

Tags: python, list, random

Say I have a list of 200 positive, unique, random integers called `masterlist`.

I want to generate a list of 10 lists called `container` so that: `l1` has 2 random numbers coming from `masterlist`, repetitions excluded; `l2` has 4 elements, `l3` has 6 elements, and so forth.

I know I can create my `container` list like this:

```
comb=[[] for i in range(10)]
```

and that I can select a random value from a list using `random.choice()`.

What is the best Pythonic way to nest the populating process of these 10 lists, so that I create one list, append the correct number of values checking that there are no repetitions, and proceed on to the next?

**EDIT**

This is my attempt:

```
comb=[[] for i in range(10)]
for j in range(1,11):
    for k in range(0,2*j):
        comb[j][k].append(random.choice(masterlist))
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: how many integers should contain each list ? can two different lists have two same numbers ?

Comment: `l1` has 2 values, `l2` has 4 values, `l3` has 6, all the way to `l10` which has 20. Yes, two different lists can have two same numbers. What matters is that in each list you don't have repetitions.

Comment: Can can 2 sublists have a number that is in both of them?

Comment: Yes, sure they can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
import random

masterlist = [i for i in range(200)]  # For example

container = [
    random.sample(masterlist, l)
    for l in range(2, 21, 2)
]
```

The container is made up of a list comprehension, setting the variable `l` to 2, 4, 6 ... 18, 20 using the `range()` call. Within each 'loop' of the comprehension, the built in `random.sample()` call does the sampling-without-replacement that you're after.

Comment: Well, fancy stuff but I got an error: `TypeError: random_sample() takes at most 1 positional argument (2 given)`. Btw thanks for explaining!

Comment: Works for me on python 2.7. What version of python are you using? Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: also, where is the `random_sample` method defined? That's not the same as the `random.sample` method I'm using.

Comment: FWIW, your `masterlist` won't contain _unique_ random _integers_. But that's easy enough to do by building a set in a `while` loop & then converting the set to a list.

Comment: Yep, sorry it was just for an example list of 'things'. The questioner states they already have that list. I'll change it to a range for clarity.

Comment: My Python version: `2.7.11 | 32-bit | (default, Mar 18 2016, 21:45:29) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]`

Comment: Traceback: `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-111-9dbee59bd6ec> in <module>()
      2 masterlist=sorted(rand['Node ID'].tolist()) #Sorted list of Node IDs for random removals
      3 
----> 4 container=[random.sample(masterlist, l) for l in range(2, 101, 2)]
      5 
      6 

mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.random_sample (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:10363)()

TypeError: random_sample() takes at most 1 positional argument (2 given)`

Comment: What does your import of random look like? It appears the error about `random_sample` is coming from numpy?

Comment: Is `masterlist` actually a list, or is it a numpy matrix? I suspect it's the latter and that's probably why it's not working.