# Python: how to merge two lists of lists together, avoiding repetitions?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of lists:

`ll1=[[17],[35,6],[47,58,86]]`

`ll2=[[19],[75,8],[17,58,86]]`

How could I merge them, perhaps in a `for` loop, creating a new list of lists `ll3`, and skipping repeated values?

The intended outcome would be:
`ll3=[[17,19],[35,6,75,8],[47,58,86]]`

Which is equal to merging the two lists of lists together and then getting rid or the repeated values.

Comment: you are trying to avoid ANY value that was in any of the previous lists during merging?

Comment: are the lists always the same size??

Comment: getting rid of repeated values usually means you still keep one of the values, do you really mean the third example should not have 58 and 86?

Comment: It doesn't make sense, because you get rid of 58 but you keep a 17.

Comment: @wim I keep the `17` because it occurs for the first time in `ll1`, but then, since I already have it, I don't need it anymore.

Comment: Is this related to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40159536/python-how-to-create-a-list-of-lists-with-increasing-length-made-of-random-num)?

Comment: @PM2Ring This is the next step

Comment: It may be a good idea to give an overview of what you're trying to do. I suspect that there may be more efficient ways to do some of the steps that you are performing. If you give us the big picture we can ensure that we aren't trying to solve an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous answers don't appear to meet your requirement that lists can be of different sizes.

My solution makes use of `set` intersections and unions. N.B. I am using Python2, change `zip_longest` to `izip_longest`.

```
ll1=[[17],[35,6],[47,58,86]]
ll2=[[19],[75,8],[17,58,86]]

from itertools import zip_longest

ll3 = []
seen = set()
for a, b in zip_longest(ll1, ll2, fillvalue=[]):
    new = (set(a) | set(b)) - seen
    ll3.append(list(new))
    seen |= new
print (ll3)
```

This will print:

```
[[17, 19], [8, 75, 35, 6], [58, 86, 47]]
```

This will also work if:

```
ll1=[[17],[35,6],[47,58,86],[5]]
ll2=[[19],[75,8],[17,58,86]]
```

returning:

```
[[17, 19], [8, 75, 35, 6], [58, 86, 47], [5]]
```

Comment: Why do I get `ImportError: cannot import name zip_longest`? Never occurred to me before. Using Python 2.7.11, 32-bit

Comment: @CF84 if you're using Python2, change the name to `izip_longest` in the import and in the `for` loop

Comment: Sorry, I made a little mistake. The intended outcome must include the `58` and `86` that I had erroneously left out. Check my edit and, again, apologies.

Comment: @CF84 I just cleaned up the bit-wise operations a bit: it's even shorter now.

Comment: @CF84 okay, luckily that's an easy fix: just change `^` to `|` (I edited accordingly)

Comment: I made a little change to the OQ based on an error that I have just picked up. The repeated values must be avoided, but must also appear once in the final `ll3`. Makes sense?

Answer (score 2):

```
seen = set()
res = []
for a, b in zip(l1, l2):
    subres = []
    for item in a:
        seen.add(item)
        if item not in b and item not in seen:
            subres.append(item)
    for item in b:
        seen.add(item)
        if item not in a and item not in seen:
            subres.append(item)
    res.append(subres)
```

Comment: ha, practically the same solution at about the same time

Comment: Consider using `set.symmetric_difference`

Comment: @PM2Ring I wanted to avoid using `set`s for `a` and `b` in case order mattered.

Comment: From the OP's previous question, I'm pretty sure that order in a sublist doesn't matter. But it's a Good Idea to get clarification on stuff like that via comments on the question.

Answer (score 1):

For what it seems like you are looking for, I would keep a set of previous values.

```
old_values =  {}
ll3 = []
for list_a, list_b in zip(ll1,ll2):
  temp_list = []
  for item in list_a:
    if item in old_values or item in list_b:
      pass
    else:
      temp_list.append(item)
      old_values.add(item)
  for item in list_b:
    if item in old_values or item in list_a:
      pass
    else:
      temp_list.append(item)
      old_values.add(item)
  ll3.append(temp_list)
```

Comment: and you could switch my conditionals to match @PatrickHaugh answer.  His is a bit cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

In general - assuming that order of elements in resulting sub-lists is not important and 2 lists are of the same length, you may use *zip* and *set*

```
ll3 = [set(l1 + l2) - set(l1).intersection(l2) for l1, l2 in zip(ll1, ll2)]
seen = set()
for idx, elem in enumerate(ll3):
    ll3[idx] = list(elem - seen)
    seen.update(elem)
```

Comment: This doesn't skip duplicate value, but instead includes one copy in the result

Comment: @volcano it's not immediately apparent in the question, but the OP also wants to exclude previous seen values (in this case, the second 17).

Comment: @brianpck, thnx for clarification, Fixed that